# Replace and write multiple data in file

Tags: python

I have a file `edit` with data

```
ABCD-(CP(),D(),SD())
GHIK-(A(),B(),C())
LMNO-(CP(),D(),CD(),CDN())
TYBV-(CPN(),DA(),SE())
```

I have another file `clocked` with data

```
CP
CPN
```

I want output as

```
ABCD-(CP(clk1),D(),SD())
GHIK-(A(),B(),C())
LMNO-(CP(clk1),D(),CD(),CDN())
TYBV-(CPN(clk1),DA(),SE())
```

I want to find data of file`clocked` in file `edit` and if match found , I want to `replace CP and CPN with CP(clk1) and CPN(clk1)` in file `edit`.

I tried code

```
fin=open('clocked','r')
fout=open('edit,'w')
for line in fin:
  if clocked in line:
    line=line.replace(clocked,clocked+"(clk1)")
    fout.write(line)
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

it worked fine but only thing is it is writing twice, as it's also searching for`CPN` and if not found it is writing data without replacing. So I am getting data repeated.

Using above I am getting output as

```
ABCD-(CP(clk1),D(),SD())
GHIK-(A(),B(),C())
LMNO-(CP(clk1),D(),CD(),CDN())
TYBV-(CPN(),DA(),SE())
ABCD-(CP(),D(),SD())
GHIK-(A(),B(),C())
LMNO-(CP(),D(),CD(),CDN())
TYBV-(CPN(clk1),DA(),SE())
```

How can I get the desired output and avoid repeating.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("clocked.txt","r") as f:
    clocked = [i.strip() for i in f.readlines()]

with open("edit.txt","r") as f:
    edit = f.readlines()

string = ""
for i in edit:
    for j in clocked:
        if j in i:
           i = i.replace(j,f"{j}(clk1)")

    string += i
with open("edit.txt","w") as f:
     f.write(string)
```